# How retrieve all language strings in office add-ins

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

current language can be get as bellow using office-js

```
Office.context.displayLanguage
```

How do i retrieve all language strings in office add-ins. such as

> fr-fr , en-US , en-GB ...

is it similar to this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/language-strings?view=vs-2019 ?

Comment: Currently, we do not have any API to retrieve all language strings. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: We don't have office js API. We have rest API though, check this link- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-supportedlanguages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: sorry only through graph api you can achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we do not have any API to retrieve all language strings. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process. We don't have office js API. We have rest API though, check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-supportedlanguages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) .